# Paste text to an active Word window using c#

Tags: c#, ms-word, copy-paste

I am developing an application that will receive data through COM port and needs to paste it into a Microsoft Office program (for now, I'm working with Word, but it will support Excel, PowerPoint, ...).

I thought that a nice idea would be copying this data to clipboard, then paste it to whatever application window is open (so, for instance, LibreOffice apps and Notepad work perfectly). For this, I've coded:

```
if (booleanIncomingData)
{
    booleanCopy = true;
}
else if (booleanOutcomingData)
{
    copy = false;
}
if (copy)
{
    Clipboard.SetText(myString);
}
else
{
    SendKeys.Send("^V");
    SendKeys.Send("{ENTER}");
}
```

As I said, LibreOffice programs and Notepad work perfectly, but Word and Excel aren't doing what I thought they should (basically display any data, then jump to the next line).

Also, a simple

```
Clipboard.GetText()ç
```

doesn't work (and my feeling is because it tries to paste the content into the active window.

Looking for Interop.Word solutions over the web, had no success so far. Does anyone have an idea what can I do or where I should look for? Instead of a regular Win32 application, should I implement an Office add-on?

In case any other information is necessary, please feel free to ask for it.

César.

Comment: Have a look at the [Primary Interop Assemblies](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa302338.aspx).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It got much more complex than I thought. But my current application now works with several softwares (Word, Excel, Notepad, LibreOffice, ...).

**COPY/PASTE DATA**

- stackoverflow.com/questions/3546016/how-to-copy-data-to-clipboard-in-c-sharp
- msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.sendkeys.send(v=vs.110).aspx

**GET THE ACTIVE WINDOW**

- www.csharphelp.com/2006/08/get-current-window-handle-and-caption-with-windows-api-in-c/
- stackoverflow.com/questions/893669/determine-whether-program-is-the-active-window-in-net
- stackoverflow.com/questions/2635404/how-to-get-process-name-and-title-of-the-top-window-on-windows-c-sharp

**MICROSOFT OFFICE**

- hubpages.com/hub/How-To-Program-with-Excel-and-C-using-a-Ribbon
- msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/6b9478cs.aspx
- stackoverflow.com/questions/13403504/send-text-to-excel-sheet-using-winapi
- stackoverflow.com/questions/2378206/how-to-get-current-or-focussed-cell-value-in-excel-worksheet-using-c-sharp

All in all, Microsoft Office applications were more cumbersome, and as @Brian suggested, PIA (Primary Interop Assemblies) were crucial in this task.

Comment: How did you get word working? This worked in most apps, but not in Office apps as you point out. Do you detect word and act differently, and automate?

Comment: @ScottHanselman basically following the links I provided... where exactly did you get stuck? In a more high-level abstraction, it was a matter of detecting the active window, making sure it was WinWord, then moving the desired data to clipboard, and finally sending a "CTRL+V" command.

Comment: Ah, I'm doing WM_PASTE like this: IntPtr hWnd = GetFocusedHandle(); PostMessage(hWnd, WM_PASTE, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero); I'll try doing SendKeys.

Comment: Weird...I ensured Word was in the front and the cursor was there, but word (on Windows 8.1 and Word 2013) just ignores the Ctrl-V. What are you using the PIAs for? Are you automating Word with its COM APIs via the PIA or is it accepting the Ctrl-V?

Comment: Ok, this is a snippet of my old code: http://pastebin.com/BGYMjtcw
I've decided, after some time, that sending SendKeys.Send() to any active window would be much more effective for what I was pursuing.

Comment: @ScottHanselman Did you ever get it working?  I am trying to build something similar but I don't want to tie it to any office applications specifically.

Comment: Yes, and a simplified solution was to use SendKeys.Send() method: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.sendkeys.send(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Thanks, you may consider to format your links and put some code snippets. Anyway thanks